# Unable to determine why code stops after printing 113383

Tags: c++

I am trying to code the first problem from programming challenges books. The code calculates number of numbers generated from a to b.
 the new n is n/2 if n is even and if its odd, its 3*n+1
 For e.g. for 22 its will calculate numbers 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 and so the number of numbers is 16.The code stops after printing 113383, i gave input as 
1 1000000

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::endl;


using std::vector;
using std::map;
map<long,long> solution;


long sequences(long n) {
// returns the number of numbers(including 1) `n`produces till it becomes 1
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else{
        // assuming n>1

        if(solution.find(n)!=solution.end())
            return solution.find(n)->second;
        long size = 0;
        while(n!=1){
            if(n%2==0){
                n = n/2;
                if(solution.find(n)!=solution.end())
                    return solution.find(n)->second + size;

            }
            else{
                n = 3*n+1;
            }
            size++;
        }
        return size+1;
    }
}
long sequences(long a,long b){
    // returns the maximum numbers produced by numbers from a to b inclusive
    long result,max = -1;
    if(a<b){
        for(long i=a;i<=b;i=i+1){
            if(solution.find(i) == solution.end()){
                cout<< i << endl;
                result = sequences(i);
                solution.insert(map<long,long>::value_type(i,result));

            }
            else{
                //i present in solution
                result = solution.find(i)->second;
            }
            if(result>max)
                max = result;
        }
        return max;
    }
    return -1;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    long a,b,max;


    cin >> a >> b;
//  while(cin>>a>>b){
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<sequences(a,b)<<endl;
    /*}*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: For me, it prints 493. Is it not correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have an overflow error. For all numbers below 113383, a signed long is sufficient to calculate the hailstone sequence without overflowing. But for a starting value of 113383, the maximum value reached during the hailstone sequence is 2482111348. That's a bit too large to be held in a signed long, whose minimum upper limit is (2^31)-1.